# Words with improper spacing text scraping pdf file

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I'm having a trouble while scraping text from pdf files using **python**.
My goal is to get the text from a pdf file ( from chapter 1 to chapter 2, for example) and write it on a docx file(or txt file). However, the text I get is full of incorrect spacing.

Text example: "
Chapter 1
Aerial seeding can quickly cover large and physically inaccessible areas1 to improve soil quality and scavenge residual nitrogen in agriculture2, and for postfire reforestation3,4,5 and wildland restoration6,7. However, it suffers from low **germination** rates, due to the direct exposure of unburied
Chapter 2
"

Text output on docx file: "
Chapter 1
Aerial seed ing can quic kly cover large and phys ically inacce ssible a reas1 to improve soil quality and scavenge residu al nitrogen in agriculture2, and for postf ire refore station3,4,5 and wil dland restorati on6,7. However, it suffers from low **germina tion** rates, due to the direct expos ure of unbur ied
Chapter 2
"

Notice that words are incorretly spaced.

My code is the following:

```
import PyPDF2
# Open the PDF file
with open('example.pdf', 'rb') as pdf_file:
    # Create a PDF reader object
    pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
    # Initialize an empty string to store the text
    text = ""
    # Loop through each page in the PDF file
    for page in range(pdf_reader.getNumPages()):
        # Extract the text from the page
        page_text = pdf_reader.getPage(page).extractText()
        # Append the page text to the overall text
        text += page_text
        # Stop extracting text after the end of chapter 1
        if "CAPÍTULO II" in page_text:
            break
# Extract the text from Chapter 1 to Chapter 2
start = text.find("Chapter 1")
end = text.find("Chapter 2")
text = text[start:end]

print(text)
# Save the extracted text to a new file
with open('extracted_text.txt', 'w') as text_file:
    text_file.write(text)
```

The expected output is the first text exactly as it is.
How can I solve this case?

Comment: The reason may be improper coding of the PDF itself. In PDF you can place each character directly at desired position. So no need to write spaces at all. Therefore extractor SW needs heuristics to **generate** space(s) when it seems appropriate. Can obviously go wrong at times. The other way round also happens: the PDF creator writes a space on a place, where another character already is present. Invisible in PDF viewers, but an extractor SW will faithfully extract that space - or must have extended logic to suppress it in those cases.

Comment: You could try another package like PyMuPDF to see if your case is covered better. That package also allows extracting on single characters basis with position info - so you can decide to ignore overlapping spaces.

Comment: It's called kerning. Not improper at all.

Comment: Which version of PyPDF2 do you use? Please upgrade to pypdf. PyPDF2 is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

If I drag a PDF onto a shortcut (One I prepared earlier)

[image]

Then it will automatically generate the text no mess no fuss just a right click or a drag and drop, HOWEVER it needs PDFtoTEXT (Xpdf or poppler, either willl do) as the Automator

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c C:\Apps\PDF\xpdf\xpdf-tools-win-4.04\bin32\pdftotext.exe -layout -nopgbrk -enc UTF-8
```

[image]

Once you have the layout text you can slice and dice it with Python, or MS NotePad with VBS or any other richer editor like WordPad

Answer (score 0):

using the tips to use the PyMuPDF I managed to get it. I used the code bellow

```
import fitz
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Pt
from docx.enum.text import WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH
# Open the PDF file
doc = fitz.open('Regulamento-GalapagosDeepOceanFICFIM06022023VF.pdf')
# Create a new Word document
document = Document()
# Set the font style for the document
font_style = document.styles['Normal']
font_style.font.size = Pt(12)

text=""
text_aux=""
# Iterate over each page in the PDF file
for page in doc:
    # Extract the text from the page
    text = page.get_text()
    # Add the text to a new paragraph in the Word document
    #paragraph = document.add_paragraph(text)
    # Set the paragraph alignment to left
    #paragraph.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.LEFT
    text_aux = text_aux + text
# Save the Word document

start = text_aux.find("CHAPTER 1")
end = text_aux.find("CHAPTER 2")
text1 = text_aux[start:end]

paragraph = document.add_paragraph(text1)
paragraph.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.LEFT

print(text1)
document.save('example_test.docx')
```

Using this code I was able to get the text with the exact format and extract the chapters as wanted.